# How to remove cookie codes from url in C#?

Tags: asp.net, .net

whenever i am redirecting to any page then in url getting like below codes
    http://localhost:16845/%28S%28bw01h320imn5pvqa540neavx%29%29/Admin/DashBoard.aspx

so when i copying this link and paste into another browser link then there same credentials using and getting logging in without give credentials.

so how to remove above coockie string>?

Comment: Set in auth config cookiless="false"

Comment: then how kill coocikes when browser get closed? because I thought this is true thats why getting clear coockies.

Comment: I did it false then also coming .

Comment: If you want cookie to expire after browser closed, use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie and pass second parameter false

Answer (score 2):

Make sure ASP.NET is not using URI cookie mode.

In IIS Manager select your site, at the top in the ASP.NET section double-click the `Session State` icon.

Towards the bottom, in `Cookie Settings` - `Mode` use `Use Cookies` or maybe `Auto Detect` but not `Use Uri`